# Android Studio Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I use an AVD with that targets API 24 everything ok.
When is use an AVD that targets API 19 I get error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cabbytech.driverapphttp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cabbytech.driverapphttp-2, /system/lib]]
```

This is my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"  
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cabbytech.driverapphttp"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-     core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

I think that there is a problem in this gradle script but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I hadn't read this

```
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
```

I implemented these steps and it worked. In the manifes under application tab:

```
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

and in the gradle script:

```
  dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  }
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, but the resource you linked saved my soul. I added `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` as suggested there and my troubles were gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using wrong virtual device image. When creating virtual device you should choose system image that support Google APIs.

Correct system image is at the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Ok I re-downloaded the correct image thanks - what was the gradle script I needed to include at the top>

Comment: I was wrong about it. Just image. Does it help you?

Comment: Unfortunately it will not run - same error as before

Comment: I created empty project with your gradle file. It run perfect on any AVD. Problem not here.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir.